# Is there a term for an estimator's probability of estimating an impossible estimand value?

Tags: loss-functions, estimators, point-estimation

This is similar to Mean Squared Error and Mean Absolute Error but in this case the loss function assigns estimates to $0$ when they are a possible estimand and $1$ when they are impossible.

As a concrete example consider the variance of a Bernoulli distribution. The only possible variance values are in the range [0, 0.25]. So like MSE, MAE, etc... given a distribution of specific parameters, one can ask with what probability does an estimator make an estimate outside that range of possible estimands.

I wrote a doc (https://castedo.com/osa/138/) where I call this "Probability of Impossible Estimand" (PIE) but surely there is an existing term I can use. What are existing terms for this?

Comment: There is never any reason to consider this situation, because any such estimator can be replaced by a version in which its impossible estimates are replaced by an estimate that *is* possible.  For instance, if somehow a variance estimator were to produce a negative number, one would replace such a value by zero.

Comment: @whuber The situation exists, regardless of it correctability. The immensely popular sample variance (with denominator of $n-1$) generates impossible estimates for a Bernoulli distribution. We can agree that this unbiased estimator is worse than the biased estimator you mention. But this unbiased estimator is popular and there is reason to evaluate it's performance.